# TinyMCE bug - @ symbol in link URL makes http://mce_host appear

Tags: tinymce

Have someone a resolution for that [annoying problem](http://sourceforge.net/tracker/index.php?func=detail&aid=3034720&group_id=103281&atid=635682)?

Comment: i wasn't able to reproduce it on the example page

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Open the file **/sites/all/modules/tinymce/tinymce.module**

Find the following function:

```
function tinymce_config($profile) {
...
}
```

Within that function, find the following line and remove it or comment it out:

```
$init['entity_encoding'] = 'raw';
```